# Unity - User presses a specific object (a button) which in turn increases or decreases their score

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and what I'm trying to create is a quiz. What I want is the user to click on an answer (Button Object) and if its right, increase the score. And if its wrong, decrease the score. However, I cant seem to find the code to increase and decrease the score. Any help with this would be highly appreciated. I have a score manager script with a starting score of 10 if that's any help. The script is following:

[image: ScoreManager script]

Comment: Please include code as text instead of image in the future. Convert the image to text an include it in a code section. Thx.

Comment: `score += somevalue` and `score -= somevalue`, where `somevalue` is however much you want to increase or decrease the score by.

Comment: Matt Burland. Where will I put that code. Within the ScoreManager script? And how would I link that to a button?

Comment: If you add a button like you did for the text, "public Button button" then you can probably register on the OnClick event and put the code @MattBurland wrote for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need some reference to check against if a given answer is correct. Lets assume you have a question and four answers (a, b, c, d).
You can give a button (the unity buttons under UI) a target method to execute on click and specify a value e.g. a string stating a, b, c or d. Therefor you need an object which has a script with that method.

I recommend having a look at this tutorial video for the button on how to set this up: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-button

In that method you then check if the answer was correct, e.g. you can have a `Dictionary<string, string>` where the first string corresponds to the question and the second one to the correct answer and if the value from the button matches this answer, the user picked the correct answer.

For further help we would need to know how you have your questions set up, how you know which is the current question, which is the correct question to that answer...